# How to add Infrastructure Agent to Heroku applications

Tags: ruby, docker, performance, heroku, newrelic

I am attempting to have the New Relic Infrastructure Agent monitor my heroku applications.

The documentation says to run the following:

```
docker run \
-d \
--name newrelic-infra \
--network=host \
--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE \
--privileged \
--pid=host \
-v "/:/host:ro" \
-v "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock" \
-e NRIA_LICENSE_KEY=[Key]\
newrelic/infrastructure:latest
```

But where do I actually run or put this so it runs it on my Heroku apps?

Comment: Would you mind adding a link to the documentation?

Comment: This:

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/infrastructure/host-integrations/installation/new-relic-guided-install-overview/

leads to an internal link that shows this:

"Copy and run the command
Use New Relic to discover what data you can send to us

The New Relic infrastructure agent monitors Docker on your host automatically.

This command will install the infrastructure agent and allow ingestion of Docker specific logs."

Comment: @user2463732 check if this [`new relic doc`](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/accounts/install-new-relic/partner-based-installation/heroku-install-new-relic-add/) and this [`heroku doc`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/newrelic) is helpful